# How to redirect 404 page to home page in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am trying to redirect 404 page to home page in magento 1.9.

From admin config->web I can set in 'cms no page' to 'Home Page' option and it is redirecting properly.

Like, 'www.example.com/abcv' which is 404 page, this redirecting to home page but in browser url is not changing.

I have tried .htaccess to ,

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

but its not working,

ANy suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the query string is not changing then it is not a redirect.

To solve your Issue without backend programming you could create custom 404 cms page and put javascript redirect in it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirectHome() {
  window.location = "{{store url=''}}";
}
setTimeout("redirectHome()", 5000);
</script>
```

otherwise you will have to write a module and add a custom frontend router

Comment: I did this solution. I didn't know it was good practice or not. I will do this anyway. Thank You

Comment: better solution would be to write a module and redirect in php. it requires backend code but it is more seamless for the user experience. Accept if it helped ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please see 404-Error-To-Home Page-Redirection.png[image]